# REST API to get all site collections in sharepoint tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, office-365, sharepoint-rest-api, jsom

Can we use REST API to get all site collections in sharepoint tenant.? I don't want powershell script basically i want to bind all asite collections to a dropdown.

my code looks like bleow.
[image: RESTAPI Serach]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SharePoint search API for that, with a query like this:

```
https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contentClass:STS_Site'&trimduplicates=false&selectproperties='SiteLogo%2cTitle'
```

This query gets all sites and selects the logo and title. You can modified to get more properties.

If you want to go the graph route, you can do it like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*
```

That'd also get you back all sites, but for simplicity (and if you're using on prem) you can just use search.

**Updated to answer the question in the comment:**

If you want to filter based on the url, you can do something like this:

```
https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contentClass:STS_Site'&trimduplicates=false&selectproperties='SiteLogo,Title,SPSiteUrl'&refinementfilters='SPSiteUrl:("https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/*")'
```

*You would want to escape the double quotes when used in code, like this:*

```
 const url =  "https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contentClass:STS_Site'&trimduplicates=false&selectproperties='SiteLogo,Title,SPSiteUrl'&refinementfilters='SPSiteUrl:(\"https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/*\")'"
```

or with escape it with backticks like this:

```
`https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contentClass:STS_Site'&trimduplicates=false&selectproperties='SiteLogo,Title,SPSiteUrl'&refinementfilters='SPSiteUrl:("https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/*")'`
```

This way you're getting only sites under /sites. or you can have something like /sites/p* to have all sites starting with the letter p.

Comment: Thanks Mohamed. This Gives me all the site collections including the personal . Is there any way where in we can Filter. For example I have internal and external site collections. Where in Internal site collectons url is https://tenanat.com/sites/Sitecolname  And external site col url is https://tenanat.com/Teams/Sitecolname  . Can we filter so that it will fetch only external and internal site collections

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: it gives me the below message {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"odata.error\":{\"code\":\"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"The query string \\\"refinementFilters\\\" is missing or invalid.\"}}}","responseJSON":{"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The query string \"refinementFilters\" is missing or invalid."}}},"status":400,"statusText":"error"}

Comment: Can you submit your full query?

Comment: Thanks Mohamed for your help. i have updated the method in my orginal question

Comment: You did not use the url in my answer. Your refinement filter is wrong, you should use SPSiteUrl rather than url. Plus you have wrong single quotes. It should be like: &refinementfilters='SPSiteUrl:("https://yourorg.sharepoint.com/sites/*")'

Comment: when i tried your code it gives me error . attached screen shot for your reference

Comment: The code in the screenshot doesn't seem to be well-formatted. You'll need to escape the double quotes. I have updated the answer to include the url to use in your code.

Comment: Thanks Mohammed that works. however it returns only some of the site collections . for example i have around 175 it returns only 61. i have include romlimit as well. Is this because of STS_Site... i have some publishing sites as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try following endpoint:

```
https://xxx-admin.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DO_NOT_DELETE_SPLIST_TENANTADMIN_AGGREGATED_SITECOLLECTIONS')/items?$select=Title,SiteUrl
```

I have tested it on my SP online and it works well.

For more details, please refer to :

- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/get-all-site-collections-of-office-365-tenant-in-ms-flow/